# How to add filter to a custom query on Data Studio?

Tags: filter, looker-studio, case-when

I'm building a dash using Data Studion and I need to create a custom query using CASE WHEN statments. The problem is that the conditions must be the values selected through a filter. How can I get the value selected on the filter and use it as a parameters on my query?

Comment: Can you show your data and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

you can not , the only parameter that can be passed from  a filter is dates as per this documentation  https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en

all you can do is vote for this feature request

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142183085